# Docker Ubuntu image missing many common binaries

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I'm comparing a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS with its equivalent Docker image/container and I'm noticing many typical binaries like `vi`, `less`, `ping`, and so on are missing from the Docker version.

Just counting binaries in some key folders from the Docker container:

```
root@9769637f38c6:/# ls -al /bin | wc -l
89
root@9769637f38c6:/# ls -al /usr/bin | wc -l
236
```

And on the fresh Ubuntu VM I get the 174 and 650 binaries, respectively.

Why are they so different?

Answer (score 1):

The main idea of `docker` - as far as I understand - is to run a service within in a small, lightweight container. For this, you not necessarily need programs such as `vi`, `less` or `ping`. If you are creating your own image with a `Dockerfile` and you need one of these files (e.g. for the service or for later debugging), you can add these through installing additional packages with this line within the `Dockerfile`

```
RUN apt -y install vim less iputils-ping
```